# "Cannot Modify Header" error when moving MediaWiki to a subfolder on localhost

Tags: php, mediawiki, localhost

I installed, configured, and populated MediaWiki on localhost and have been maintaining my wiki locally for 4 years. Today I simply dragged the mediawiki folder into a subfolder I created for better organization and now the site is broken.

### Errors

Here are the debugs at the top (they were the exact same messages before, just a different   path now, as noted below).

##### Top of Page:

[image: hepperlepedia2 localhost: PHP debugging errors, top]

##### Bottom of Page:

[image: hepperlepedia2 localhost: PHP debugging errors, bottom]

**NOTE:** The errors at the top are about `continue` vs `break` statements, whereas the bottom errors are mostly "*cannot modify headers*"

### What I've Tried Already

1. Changed `$wgScriptPath` from

`$wgScriptPath = "/hepperlepedia2"` to `$wgScriptPath = "/sub/wiki/hepperlepedia2"`

2. Tried following MediaWiki directions. [This page](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Moving_a_wiki) says directions for moving a wiki into a subfolder are here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763909/mediawiki-on-subdirectory-and-subdomain. I followed these steps:

- (Already modified `$wgScriptPath` as indicated above)
- Restarted WampServer, which restarted apache
- Navigated to http://localhost/sub/wiki/hepperlepedia2/

[image: MediaWiki on SubDirectory and SubDomain]

Note, the site worked fine -- nothing was changed moving the mediawiki folder ("hepperlepedia2") into a subfolder. That's when I started getting all these debug errors.

### My Question

I know that the debug screen means the path to the home/main/index page of the wiki must be working. ***But, why am I getting all these errors on things I didn't even change? If changing $wgScriptPath in `LocalSettings.php` didn't prevent these errors, what will?*** I suspect there is a setting or variable value somewhere that needs to be set, but I don't know what it would be.

Comment: Which version of MediaWiki and PHP do you use?

Comment: @AlexanderMashin Your question seems to indicate that an update to a different version might help. But, why would that be when that wiki install used to work just fine. I didn't change anything in that codebase. If I didn't change anything there, what else could be affecting it?